# RO:09-RI:10-PO:05-PI-22

Tags: cipher

One of my friends who is good with cyphers and puzzles challenged me to solve this one. I think it reveals a name, or date or some information with which he can surprise his friends. I couldn't find similar puzzles on the Internet.

> **RO:09-RI:10-PO:05-PI-22**

Comment: @AmitMandal are you sure this is the whole puzzle?

Comment: @VarunW.Been a long time, don't even know why I posted it :P